# Unity XR cannot recognize controller devices via script

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am trying to use my oculus quest to develop some hand controls with the oculus touch controllers. However, the script I'm using is unable to detect my touch devices for some reason while it looks perfectly functional from the XR interaction Debugger and is even functional when using the XR Direct Interactor component provided by the XR Interaction Toolkit.

The script I'm using to test the controls is as follows:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR;

public class HandController : MonoBehaviour
{
    List<InputDevice> devices = new List<InputDevice>();

    void Start()
    {
        InputDevices.GetDevices(devices);


        foreach (var item in devices)
        {
            Debug.Log(item.name + item.characteristics);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        foreach(var item in devices)
        {
            Debug.Log(item.name + item.characteristics);
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the console and XR Interaction Debugger outputs for reference:

[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gtPQ.jpg)
[XR Interaction Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYDWn.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I've opened a new project and reinstalled the necessary packages again and it seems to have fixed this particular issue. My guess is, this was because there were some conflicts between the XR interaction package and the Oculus OVR package I had installed to test out different things earlier in the project.